# Почему — долговязый?

Tags: этимология

О высоком и худом человеке говорят, что он долговязый. Интересно было бы узнать происхождение тут корня "-вяз-". При чем тут вязание?

Answer (score 1):

Изначально "вязы" (мн. ч.) -- шея (см. [[1]](http://krylov.academic.ru/968) и [[2]](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/39130)).
Т. обр., "долговязый" значит "длинношеий".

Answer (score 1):

> ***Долговя́зый*** из "до́лгий" и "вяз" от vęzъ "шея", первоначально "длинношеий"...

А со временем - длинноногий. Вязание же при том, что "вязы" то, что "связывает туловище с головой".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Желательно всё же не прикладывать картинки, особенно учитывая, что ничего кроме текста в ней нет.